# .htaccess insert a word on url and 301 redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Our url structure is as follows:

> www.domain.com/browse-technology-videos-1-date.html
>
> www.domain.com/browse-technology-videos-1-rating.html
>
> www.domain.com/browse-technology-videos-1-views.html
>
> www.domain.com/browse-technology-videos-1-title.html

the new structure would be:

> www.domain.com/browse-science-and-technology-videos-1-date.html
>
> www.domain.com/browse-science-and-technology-videos-1-rating.html
>
> www.domain.com/browse-science-and-technology-videos-1-views.html
>
> www.domain.com/browse-science-and-technology-videos-1-title.html

all these are generated urls so the point is just adding -science-and where there was technology alone in the url and redirect the old structure to the new structure

How can we achieve this?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#if www.domain.com is important for you, remove the # of next line
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^browse-technology-(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/browse-science-and-technology-$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here's another case:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/browse-art-and-cinema
RewriteRule ^browse-art-(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/browse-art-and-cinema-$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks it is working, but we have another category where the actual url is as follows:


    www.domain.com/browse-art-videos-1-date.html

    www.domain.com/browse-art-videos-1-rating.html

    www.domain.com/browse-art-videos-1-views.html

    www.domain.com/browse-art-videos-1-title.html

and the new is:

Comment: so what you want with these urls?

Comment: thanks it is working, but we have another category where the actual url is as follows:


    www.domain.com/browse-art-videos-1-date.html

and the new is:

    www.domain.com/browse-art-and-cinema-videos-1-date.html

   we have applyed the above for this category:
RewriteRule ^browse-art-(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/browse-art-and-cinema-$1 [R=301,L]

but it is giving redirection error rewriting and-cinema-and-cinema-and-cinema again and again, how could we acomplish what we are looking for this??

thanks again

Comment: See the new answer, just add a RewriteCond